# OpenLDAP: TLS error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: ssl, openldap

I'm not familiar with certificates and `openldap`.  I'm trying to port someone elses work from an older OS to `CentOS-6` with `openldap-2.4.23`.  On the old OS, an ldap connection worked without issue.  Now on `CentOS-6`, I get the following error when doing a simple bind:

`TLS error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized`.

My `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` has a single line:

```
TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/openldap/certs
```

I tried commenting out that line and putting the following into the file but that didn't change the error message I received.

```
tls_reqcert allow
```

I also tried putting only the following line in `ldap.conf` but that didn't change the error.  I tried this based on information found in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/437546/centos-openldap-cert-trust-issues).

```
LDAPTLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I copied files into the following directories:

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt

/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt

/etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
```

I have no choice but to use `openldap-2.4.23`.  Any idea what is causing this error or what I can do to troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance. 
SP

Answer (score 4):

As per http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ldap-conf.html `TLS_CACERT` should point to the file containing the `CA cert` that the client will use to verify the certificate.  You need to make sure the your servers CA [The CA that signed your server certificate] is present in the file that `TLS_CACERT` points to[in your case `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. In my case the reason was, that my client had the wrong certificate in /etc/ipa/ca.crt. To fix this, I just copied /etc/ipa/ca.crt from the KDC server to the client and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the environment, OpenLDAP may completely ignore the value set for `TLS_CACERTDIR` because evidently GnuTLS doesn't support that type of certificate store.

From the man page for `ldap.conf(5)`

```
   TLS_CACERTDIR <path>
          Specifies the path of a directory that contains  Certifi‐
          cate Authority certificates in separate individual files.
          The TLS_CACERT is always used before TLS_CACERTDIR.  This
          parameter is ignored with GnuTLS.
```

In my case, I suspect that GnuTLS is in use, so `TLS_CACERTDIR` simply does nothing. Using `TLS_CACERT` pointed to a file containing the certificate of my server's signing CA seems to have done the trick.

I think https://serverfault.com/questions/437546/centos-openldap-cert-trust-issues is a much more complete answer.